# JavaFX Undecorated StageStyle will keep the windows taskbar visible

Tags: java, javafx, kotlin

Hi I'm making a JavaFX UI and I want it to be Undecorated, however, when I run the program it will keep my windows taskbar visible, is there a way to work around this?

```
class MagicBar: Application()
{

override fun start(primaryStage: Stage?)
{
    stage = Stage()
    val fxmlLoader = FXMLLoader()
    val root = fxmlLoader.load<Parent>(javaClass.getResource("/MagicBar.fxml").openStream())
    controller = fxmlLoader.getController<MagicBarController>() as MagicBarController
    stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED)
    val scene = Scene(root, 600.0, 80.0)
    stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT)
    scene.fill = Color.TRANSPARENT
    stage.scene = scene
    stage.isAlwaysOnTop = true
    stage.show()
}

}
```

Comment: Go fullscreen??

Comment: I don't want to go fullscreen my UI is very small and fullscreen would waste too much screen real estate, I want it to work in cooperation with whatever is currenly running on the desktop.

Comment: Don't use Popup windows as they won't show on top of windows taskbar. Stages on the other hand may ignore the taskbar and show on top of it.

Comment: If you want to make your windows taskbar disappear just set it to autohide, you can't control the visibilty of windows taskbar via JavaFX, you can only go fullscreen, or maximized.